# How can I check if a variable is not null and also a number?

Tags: javascript

I am using the following:

```
$scope.option.selectedSubject != null && !isNaN($scope.option.selectedSubject)
```

Can someone tell me if there is another way to check if a variable is a valid defined number? Is there some way I can do this with just one check or how can I create a function to do this check and then call that ?

Comment: Why? What's the problem with that check? As for putting this in a function, Google will help you in a practical instant with this.

Comment: a string, an object, a function are all not `NaN`

Comment: @MathewFoscarini, `isNaN` will check if the numeric representation of the value is `NaN`. this means that `isNaN('500')` is `false`, while `isNaN('foo')` is `true`.

Comment: Well I am already using !isNaN.  However will this report True if the number is null or not defined?

Comment: @grant - There is nothing wrong with the check however I am wondering if there is a better way. I have 30 of these checks in my code in different places and with different variables. If there is some simpler way I would like to use that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be useful to know: A variable can only be `null` when somewhere in your script it's being assigned, it will never be `null` by default.

```
var foo; // undefined
foo = null;
// null could be returned by a function too, which is the most common use of null
```

As **zzzzBov** stated in his comment, "`isNaN` will check if the numeric representation of the value is NaN. this means that `isNaN('500')` is `false`, while `isNaN('foo')` is `true`."

As to answer your question, check this table:

```
!isNaN(undefined); // false
!isNaN(null); // true
!isNaN(); // false
!isNaN(''); // true <= Watch out for this one !
!isNaN('test'); // false
!isNaN('10'); // true
!isNaN(10); // true
```

If you want to make sure it's a number, you should use `typeof`, then if this is a string, check if it has a length. Wrapping this all in a function would create something like:

```
function isNumber (num) {
    // Return false if num is null or an empty string
    if (num === null || (typeof num === "string" && num.length === 0)) {
        return false;
    }

    return !isNaN(num);
}

isNumber(undefined); // false
isNumber(null); // false
isNumber(); // false
isNumber(''); // false
isNumber('test'); // false
isNumber('10'); // true
isNumber(10); // true
```

Comment: Can I ask why the check for num.length < 1. Is that just to check if it's between 0 and 9 ?

Comment: @Alan only because it's shorter than `=== 0` and there are no strings with a negative lengths.

Comment: I am sorry but can you explain the === 0. Will your code return true for the number zero which is what I need it to do?

Comment: @Alan `isNumber(0)` will return true. `< 1` and `=== 0` check the length of the string, not the value it contains.

Answer (score 3):

maybe this function might help you :

```
function isANumber(x) {
 return ((+x)===x);
}
```

Comment: This looks very interesting. Would this still work okay if x was null or undefined ?

Comment: +undefined is NaN so +undefined !== undefined. +null === 0 so +null !== null

Comment: @Alan `null` and `undefined` return `false`. Just undefined `var` that would give error, but then again, it's a referenceerror (of var not defined) rather than script error.

Comment: clever and cryptic at the sametime.

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick if you care only about numeric presentation.

```
!isNaN($scope.option.selectedSubject + "")
```

Notice the `+ ""`

Comment: Will that work also if the $scope.option.selectedSubject is not defined or null ?

Comment: What do you mean "numeric presentation" ?

Comment: @Alan: yes, you could try it. "numeric presentation" here i mean it does not check for datatype. For example: "500" is a string but still passes this check